# C++: Moving an element from Front of queue To Back

Tags: c++, queue, frontend

I'm attempting to write a function called `move_to_rear` that moves the element at the front of the queue to the back of the queue, then making the element second in line the front element. I was able to do this using a couple different methods, but my classmate told me he did it by using just push, front, and pop.

How did he accomplish such a thing using just those three functions?

Comment: How did you do it? Show us your code.

Comment: By definition a queue is First In First Out, so `pop` removes the element at the front of the queue and `push` pushes an element onto the back of the queue. I think you are confusing a queue with a stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something but since its a queue and not a stack the answer is simple:

```
const Item first = q.front(); //getting the first
q.pop(); //removing him
q.push(first); //adding him back to the queue (which will be in the rear)
```

Just to make sure you understand:
Queue pops the first item in the queue, and pushes items into the back. FIFO = First In First Out.
Stack pops the last item in the list, and pushes items into the back too. LIFO = Last In First Out.
value of `first` must be const because `front` return reference and may be do not push when scopes are closed.

Comment: Wow, i was thinking of stacks the whole time, thats where the confusion came from. THANKS!